# Memory management in IOS application 

Tags: iphone, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am developing an IOS application and i will submit it the next week the Apple store. but i am not very good in memory management.

1. I would like to know what are the all tools that you use to remove all the memory erros ( leaks,...).
2. should i remove all the NSLogs before submit it to the store ?
3. What are the other things to take care before submit it to the store ?

thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before submitting to the app store..

1. Detect all leaks, you can use

   **a)** Leaks (xcode->instruments->leaks).

   **b)** Static analyzer tools, if you are using newer versions of xcode (Build-> build and analyze).

   **c)** Above all , make a thorough check yourselves, that you arereleasing all memory that you are allocing/retaining..
2. What the need of NSLog in a
   distribution build. NSLog helps in
   debug..Remove them all..
3. Run your app in whatever iphone
   device you get..Never submit an
   iphone app to store without checking
   on device itself.
4. If your app crashed during review,
   then it is surely rejected. Resolve
   all bugs/crashes before submitting.
   A good QC on device is a must.

[This](http://www.makayama.com/checklist.html) checklist might be helpful..

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode , `Instruments` -> `Leaks`, is used basically to find out memory leaks.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Instruments -> Allocations also would be useful to check memory. From this we can come to know that whether any un wanted objects are still in memory.

Answer (score 0):

The static analyzer and the instruments will help you detect the leaks. Find and resolve them. Have a look at [Memory management](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011-SW1) it will help to resolve leaks.